# .filter() returns an empty array but array of objects is full before

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to extract data from JSON file and then filter it, but after .filter() I get an empty array. This is just one object in my JSON file:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Intel Core i5-11600K Desktop Processor",
        "description-short": "11th Gen Intel Core i5-11600K unlocked desktop processor with 6 cores and 12 threads, up to 4.9 GHz boost frequency, and PCIe 4.0 support.",
        "description-long": "loooong",
        "price": "$269.99",
        "image_url": "",
        "category": "CPU",
        "brand": "Intel",
        "availability": "In stock",
        "image_name": "intel-core-i5-11600k",
        "product_url": "detail.html"
    }]
}
```

It is a valid JSON. This is my JS code which takes category of a product from URL (http://localhost/myprojects/category.html?category=CPU) and then based on category my JSON data should be filtered. ProductsArray is not empty before .filter(), but I don't get anything after the filter. My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the category from the URL
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const category = urlParams.get('category');
  
    // Fetch the data from the JSON file
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/myprojects/data.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(Array.isArray(data));
        const productsArray = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
    
        console.log(productsArray)
        // Filter the products by category
        const products = productsArray.filter(product => product.category === category); //problem ig?
        
  
        // Loop through each product and update the HTML
        products.forEach(function(product, index) {
          const productId = index + 1;
          const productImageId = `product-image-${productId}`;
          const productNameId = `product-name-${productId}`;
          const productPriceId = `product-price-${productId}`;
          const productUrlClass = `product-url-${productId}`;
  
          // Update the product image
          document.getElementById(productImageId).innerHTML = `<a href="${product.url}"><img src =  "${product.image}" alt="${product.name}"></a>`;
  
          // Update the product name
          document.getElementById(productNameId).innerHTML = `<a href="${product.url}">${product.name} </a>`;
  
          // Update the product price
          document.getElementById(productPriceId).innerHTML = `$${product.price}`;
  
          /*
          // Update the product URL
          const productUrlElements = document.getElementsByClassName(productUrlClass);
          for (let i = 0; i < productUrlElements.length; i++) {
            productUrlElements[i].href = product.url;
          }
          */
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
```

I verified that productsArray is not empty before .filter(), I also checked for syntax errors.

Comment: What exactly is your filtering criteria (in words)?

Comment: What is the point of this? `const productsArray = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);` Is there ever more than one key in the object?

Comment: It looks like you want `const productsArray = data.products;` instead.

Comment: `Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])` is equivalent to `Object.values(data)`

Comment: If you had looked carefully at `console.log(productsArray)` you would have seen that it's a 2-dimensional array. Your filter expects a 1-d array of objects.